# GoogleAnalytics上に報告されるクラッシュについて

Tags: objective-c, realm

iPhoneアプリを開発しています(コードはすべてObjective-Cで書いています)。
RealmObjective-C-1.0.2を使用したバージョンをつい先日公開しました。
(iOS7をサポートするため、Static Frameworkを使用しています。)
デイリーのアクティブユーザが3万人程いて、毎日150件くらい以下のようなクラッシュがAnalytics上で報告されます。

[image: Crash on Analytics]

> "RLMException Trace: _Z23RLMAddNotificationBlockIN5realm7ResultsEEP20RLMNotificationTokenP11objc_objectRT_U13block_pointerFvS5_P19RLMCollectionChangeP7"

私のアプリではAddNotificationなどのRealmから通知を受け取るようなものは全く使用していません。
これはRealmのバグでしょうか？

Comment: `addNotificationBlock:`を呼ばない限りはこのメソッドが呼ばれることはありませんので、どこかで使っていると思います。念のため本当に使ってないかどうか再度確認してもらえますか？使ってるライブラリなどでRealmを使ってるものがあったりしませんか？後、もう少し詳細（スタックとレースの前後など）の情報をいただけますか？現状では`RLMAddNotificationBlock`で例外が起こっているということしかわかりません。

Comment: GoogleAnalytics上で報告されているもので、XCodeのOrganizerなどでは確認できていないためStacktraceは取れませんでした。
ただクライアント側のエラーをサーバー側に記録しているものがあったので確認してみたところ、
Exception Reason="No space left on device"となっていてユーザ側に領域がないためのようでした。
そのためアプリの対応としてはなにもしないで放置しようと思っています。
ただ、再度確認しても私のコード内でaddNotificationBlock:を使用している箇所がないので、気持ち悪さは残りますが…

Comment: ちなみに使用していたのは以下の３箇所のみでした。 １．objectsWithPredicate:で不要になった過去のデータを検索し(RLMResults)、RLMReal‌​m(deleteObjects:)に渡し‌​て削除している箇所 ２．サーバから取得した新しいデータをRLMRealm(addOrUpdateObject:)で更新している箇所 ３．objectsWithPredicate:でデータを検索する箇所 ライブラリはRealmを使用する前から使っているもので、内部でRealmを使用しているものはないと思っています。 少ない情報のみで質問してしまい申し訳ありませんでした。